# Genymotion Android emulator will not start in AMD Ryzen CPU

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion, amd-processor

I am trying to start an android emulator for React Native development on my machine with an AMD Ryzen 5 1600 CPU and ASRock B450 Pro4 motherboard. I tried Android studio with no luck, so I decided to try Genymotion.

When I try and start an Android 9 or 10 emulator, I get the "Your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies" error, even though I have done the following steps:

1. BIOS > Advanced > CPU Configuration > SVM Mode -> set enabled
2. BIOS > Advanced > North Bridge Configuration > IOMMU -> set enabled.
3. Hyper V > Disabled
4. Windows Hypervisor Platform > Enabled
5. Memory integrity > disabled

Answer (score 1):

Windows Hypervisor Platform must be **disabled**, not enabled.